# Angular JS: IE Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I'm stuck with a issue relating IE.

Here is the IE Error that I'm getting.

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Timestamp: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 04:00:46 UTC


Message: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var oldUrl = $browser.url();\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {\n\tchangeCounter++;\n\t$rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n\t  if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl).\n\t      defaultPrevented) {\n\t    $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n\t  } else {\n\t    $browser.url($location.absUrl(), $location.$$replace);\n\t    $location.$$replace = false;\n\t    afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n\t  }\n\t});\n      }\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    }; newVal: 7; oldVal: 6"],["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var oldUrl = $browser.url();\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {\n\tchangeCounter++;\n\t$rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n\t  if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl).\n\t      defaultPrevented) {\n\t    $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n\t  } else {\n\t    $browser.url($location.absUrl(), $location.$$replace);\n\t    $location.$$replace = false;\n\t    afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n\t  }\n\t});\n      }\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    }; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var oldUrl = $browser.url();\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {\n\tchangeCounter++;\n\t$rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n\t  if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl).\n\t      defaultPrevented) {\n\t    $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n\t  } else {\n\t    $browser.url($location.absUrl(), $location.$$replace);\n\t    $location.$$replace = false;\n\t    afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n\t  }\n\t});\n      }\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    }; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var oldUrl = $browser.url();\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {\n\tchangeCounter++;\n\t$rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n\t  if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl).\n\t      defaultPrevented) {\n\t    $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n\t  } else {\n\t    $browser.url($location.absUrl(), $location.$$replace);\n\t    $location.$$replace = false;\n\t    afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n\t  }\n\t});\n      }\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    }; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var oldUrl = $browser.url();\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {\n\tchangeCounter++;\n\t$rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n\t  if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl).\n\t      defaultPrevented) {\n\t    $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n\t  } else {\n\t    $browser.url($location.absUrl(), $location.$$replace);\n\t    $location.$$replace = false;\n\t    afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n\t  }\n\t});\n      }\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    }; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"]]
Line: 7859
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/__assets__/lib/angular/angular.js
```

This is not happening in any other browser but IE 8 and IE 9.

I have a watch looking at a content filtering object which includes a location filter.

My question with this is why doesn't it happen on any other browser but IE and what should I do to get rid of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure that one out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same issue with error which looked the same. Chrome\FF worked fine, but IE failed. I've clicked on some links in my app and sometimes got this error and sometimes not.

1) In my view I had few links which looked like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="addIP(ip)">Add some IP</a>
```

2) Click handler for those links added new object into IpRanges collection like this:

```
$scope.IpRanges.push(ip);
```

3) Collection itself was binded on view by ng-repeat, and I thought that somehow IE could not handle this situation well - probably order of binding\adding\applying events wasn't incorrect or else... Also after click on links I had # symbol added to url, and sometimes it blinked, and then I've got an error. So I removed href attribute and everything worked fine:

```
<a href="" ng-click="addCurrentIP()">Add as allowed IP</a>
```

Probably it's better to use spans or divs for similar situations.

Comment: This is the post of love!

Comment: hey thanks a lot!! I spent a lot of time but this solved my issue!!

Comment: Removing the entire href attribute did it for me

Answer (score 30):

Tiago Roldão is definitely right. I had exact the same issue. After debug, I realized in my code I have

```
location.hash = "#/app/" + id;
```

which causes the infinitely loop issue. After some research, I found this

```
$location.path("/apps/" + id);
```

which solves my issue perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would have died without finding out this

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue using AngularJS v1.2.13 in IE9, IE10, when calling $window.history.back() (especially in Windows Phone).

It seems the root cause is that $window.history.back() in IE changes the href right before the $locationWatch() is fired hence oldUrl would contain the new Url and that throws off the angular into an infinite $digest.

The immediate work around is to replace the calls to $window.history.back() with the following:

```
setTimeout(function () 
{
    $window.history.back();
}, 0);
```

Comment: Bravo! Solves my issue... Out of curiosity - how did you figured that out? I wonder if you have an established process of debugging issues on Windows Phone?

Comment: Just use IE 11 or IE10 for debugging the website and emulate the right device and document mode, it will do it 99% of the times

Comment: It solved my issue. But I would like to know how "setTimeout" solved the issue

Comment: Other solution of this problem:

$timeout(function () {
  history.go(-1);
});

Answer (score 5):

I can tell from your error report you have a $watch for a changeCounter variable, and this watcher function:

```
function $locationWatch() {
    var oldUrl = $browser.url();
    if (!changeCounter || oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {
        changeCounter++;
        $rootScope.$evalAsync(function () {
            if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl)
                .defaultPrevented) {
                $location.$$parse(oldUrl);
            } else {
                $browser.url($location.absUrl(), $location.$$replace);
                $location.$$replace = false;
                afterLocationChange(oldUrl);
            }
        });
    }
    return changeCounter;
};
```

And the changeCounter gets it's value incremented if $browser.url() doesn't equal $location.absUrl(). As the $watch function can only do 10 loops of change/reaction, it will err after those 10 iterations. As you are changing the value you are watching, it eventually breaks.

I would log those values - $location.absUrl() and $browser.url(), and see why the match in other browsers, but not in ie.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tiago. But got to tell you that this isn't a function that I wrote. It is a function that angular.js provides as a library function.

Comment: And that is watched by AngularJS in addtion.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing issue in IE 10.
I was using

```
window.location.href = '#/';
```

for changing the route.
Replacing it with
 below code

```
$location.path('/');
```

resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR

If you are using [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) then you can also use

```
$state.go('details', {id:item.ID});
```

### Background

I was using the following function to navigate from a list view to a details view so that you can click anything with `ng-click="details(item)"`, in my case `tr`'s in the list:

```
$scope.details = function (item) {
    $window.location.href = "#/details/" + item.ID;
}
```

But I was getting the dreaded `10 $digest() iterations reached` in IE.

### FYI

I placed a breakpoint in AngularJS v1.2.0rc1 angular.js line 7650 following Tiago's answer.

```
// update browser
var changeCounter = 0;
$rootScope.$watch(function $locationWatch() {
  var oldUrl = $browser.url();
  var currentReplace = $location.$$replace;

  if (!changeCounter || oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {
    changeCounter++; /* <-- breakpoint here, line 7650 */
    $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
      if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl).
          defaultPrevented) {
        $location.$$parse(oldUrl);
      } else {
        $browser.url($location.absUrl(), currentReplace);
        afterLocationChange(oldUrl);
      }
    });
  }
  $location.$$replace = false;

  return changeCounter;
});
```

### Results

Output from Chrome

- The breakpoint was only hit once the details page was loading and once only.
- `oldUrl` (i.e. `$browser.url()` was reporting the old url (i.e. the list one)
- `$location.absUrl()` was reporting the details url.

Output from IE7,8

- The breakpoint was hit continuously.
- `oldUrl` (i.e. `$browser.url()` was reporting the new url (i.e. the details one)
- `$location.absUrl()` was still reporting the list url.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to redirect to other page as

```
$window.location.href = '#/path/'
```

solved by changing to:

```
$location.path('/path/');
```