# Angularjs JavaScript runtime error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use bootstrap 2.3.x with angularjs to create a menu bar for my webpage as shown below.

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse" >
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li ng-repeat="menu in headerMenus" class={{menu.active}}>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="MenuClicked(menu)">{{menu.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller is defined as below

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ ]);

myApp.controller('ctrl', function ctrl($scope) {

  $scope.headerMenus = [
    { 'name': 'Home ',
        'link': 'index.html'
    },
    { 'name': 'Our Services',
        'link': 'services.html',
        'active': 'active'
    },
    { 'name': 'About Us',
        'link': 'about_us.html'
    },
    { 'name': 'Portfolio',
        'link': 'portfolio.html'
    },
    { 'name': 'Support',
        'link': 'contact.html'
    }
  ];

  $scope.MenuClicked = function(menu){
    alert('Clicked:' + menu.link);    
  }
});
```

now after I click on the menu a few times, angular is throwing the following error:

> **JavaScript runtime error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!**
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function
>   $locationWatch() {\n      var oldUrl = $browser.url();\n      var
>   currentReplace = $location.$$replace;\n\n      if (!changeCounter ||
>   oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {\n        changeCounter++;\n
>   $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n          if
>   ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(),
>   oldUrl).\n              defaultPrevented) {\n
>   $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n          } else {\n
>   $browser.url($location.absUrl(), currentReplace);\n
>   afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n          }\n        });\n      }\n
>   $location.$$replace = false;\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    };
>   newVal: 8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var
>   oldUrl = $browser.url();\n      var currentReplace =
>   $location.$$replace;\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl !=
>   $location.absUrl()) {\n        changeCounter++;\n
>   $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n          if
>   ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(),
>   oldUrl).\n              defaultPrevented) {\n
>   $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n          } else {\n
>   $browser.url($location.absUrl(), currentReplace);\n
>   afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n          }\n        });\n      }\n
>   $location.$$replace = false;\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    };
>   newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var
>   oldUrl = $browser.url();\n      var currentReplace =
>   $location.$$replace;\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl !=
>   $location.absUrl()) {\n        changeCounter++;\n
>   $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n          if
>   ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(),
>   oldUrl).\n              defaultPrevented) {\n
>   $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n          } else {\n
>   $browser.url($location.absUrl(), currentReplace);\n
>   afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n          }\n        });\n      }\n
>   $location.$$replace = false;\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    };
>   newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var
>   oldUrl = $browser.url();\n      var currentReplace =
>   $location.$$replace;\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl !=
>   $location.absUrl()) {\n        changeCounter++;\n
>   $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n          if
>   ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(),
>   oldUrl).\n              defaultPrevented) {\n
>   $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n          } else {\n
>   $browser.url($location.absUrl(), currentReplace);\n
>   afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n          }\n        });\n      }\n
>   $location.$$replace = false;\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    };
>   newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"],["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var
>   oldUrl = $browser.url();\n      var currentReplace =
>   $location.$$replace;\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl !=
>   $location.absUrl()) {\n        changeCounter++;\n
>   $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n          if
>   ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(),
>   oldUrl).\n              defaultPrevented) {\n
>   $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n          } else {\n
>   $browser.url($location.absUrl(), currentReplace);\n
>   afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n          }\n        });\n      }\n
>   $location.$$replace = false;\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    };
>   newVal: 12; oldVal: 11"]]

if i comment out the `ng-click` on the menu I have no issues. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

This issue goes away when I comment out the `href="#"` or the `ng-click`, but both together, it fails.

Comment: Check out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853844/angular-js-ie-error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting

Answer (score 0):

Your controller definition looks a bit off. Try using this:

```
myApp.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: you are correct, it was the typo in my post. issue is somehow related to the href="#" and ng-click being used together.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do you need the extra `href`?