# AngularJS and phantomjs snapshot error with %20 URLs

Tags: angularjs, seo, gruntjs, phantomjs

I am writing html snapshot support for a website for SEO. We have an AngularJS site running on nodejs and express.  I am installing everything via npm.

I am seeing an error when I snap-shoot pages that have an escaped character (e.g. %20 in my case).

I have tried running with grunt and grunt-html-snapshot.  In this example, both URLs work in a browser.  The URL without the escape also snapshots ok.  But the url with the %20 causes a loop error (a digest loop error?) in phantom/angular.

Here is the **gruntfile**:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html-snapshot');

  grunt.initConfig({
    htmlSnapshot: {
      all: {
        options: {
          snapshotPath: 'snapshots/',
          sitePath: 'http://localhost/', 
//          urls: ['courses/BiologicalAnthropology/']
            urls: ['courses/Biological%20Anthropology/']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['htmlSnapshot']);
};
```

Here is the console output for the error:

```
Running "htmlSnapshot:all" (htmlSnapshot) tas    k    
running html-snapshot task...hold your horses    
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!    
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 7;     ol    d    Val: 6"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal:     8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: $locationWatch;     newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],["fn:     $l    o    cationWatch; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"]]    
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%    3A%    2    0%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%207%3B%20oldVal%3A%206%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%    20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%208%3B%20oldVal%3A%207%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%    3A%    2    0%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%209%3B%20oldVal%3A%208%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%    20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%2010%3B%20oldVal%3A%209%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn    %3A    %    20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%2011%3B%20oldVal%3A%2010%22%5D%5D    
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js:1    207    3    
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js:1    227    9    
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js:1    385    
    at invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angu    lar    .js:3805)    
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js:1    386    
    at bootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/a    ngular.js:1394)    
    at angularInit (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15    /angular.js:1307)    
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js:2    1163    
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2    
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2    
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2    
    at K (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:    2)    
error: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!    
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 7; oldVal: 6"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal:     8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: $locationWatch;     newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"]]    
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%207%3B%20oldVal%3A%206%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%    20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%208%3B%20oldVal%3A%207%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%209%3B%20oldVal%3A%208%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%    20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%2010%3B%20oldVal%3A%209%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%2011%3B%20oldVal%3A%2010%22%5D%5D
```

I have also tried running a plain vanilla phantomjs script to snapshot the page, but get similar errors with that approach.

**Server Script (PhantomJS):**

```
var path = require('path')
var childProcess = require('child_process')
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs')
var binPath = phantomjs.path

var childArgs = [
  path.join(__dirname, '../phantom/test.js'),
  'http://localhost/courses/Biological%20Anthropology'
]

console.log(childArgs);

childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(err, stdout, stderr);
  // handle results
})
```

**Phantom script:**

```
var system = require( "system" );
var page = require( "webpage" ).create();
var url = system.args[1];
var t = Date.now();
console.log(url);

page.open( url, function( status ) {
   console.log( 'Load time: ' + (Date.now() - t) + 'ms' );

} );


page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    console.log('On load finished Status: ' + status);

    var pageContent = page.evaluate( function() {
        return document.getElementsByTagName( "html" )[0].innerHTML;
    } );

    console.log(pageContent);

    phantom.exit();
};
```

Here's the first line of the console error (after that it repeats angular includes and code indefinitely):

```
[Error: stdout maxBuffer exceeded.] 'http://localhost/courses/Biological%20Anthropology/\r\nError: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!\r\nWatchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 7; oldVal: 6"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"]]\r\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%207%3B%20oldVal%3A%206%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%208%3B%20oldVal%3A%207%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%209%3B%20oldVal%3A%208%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%2010%3B%20oldVal%3A%209%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%2011%3B%20oldVal%3A%2010%22%5D%5D\r\n\r\n
```

The only thing I found on stack overflow related was this discussion on client side angular implementation and browser compatibility.  They were seeing a similar error message:

[Angular JS: IE Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853844/angular-js-ie-error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting)

And I found a brief google group discussion with an unsatisfactory answer (disable html5mode):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/Gna-zWBJhIE/CBYhCJ_1lXIJ

Comment: Have you tried to replace `%20` in your grunt file/phantom script with a space?

Comment: Yep. I tried replacing with a space.  That did not work either.