# Angular controller loads only the first time in IE

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to setup a controller that will redirect a user to a defined home page when they navigate to a specific url.  This is so different users can all have their own landing page.

I have a state

```
.state('database.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: "app/Database/Home/home.html",
    controller: "DatabaseHomeController"
})
```

and a controller

```
(function (ng, app) {

  "use strict";

  app.controller(
      "DatabaseHomeController",
      ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$state", "$stateParams", "sessionService", function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams, sessionService) {

          console.log("Database home controller running");

          $stateParams.systemName = sessionService.auth.DefaultSystem;
          $stateParams.objectName = sessionService.auth.Homepage;

          if ($stateParams.objectName) {
              $state.transitionTo("database.object", $stateParams);
          } else {
              $state.transitionTo("login");
          }
      }]);
})
(angular, WebAppName);
```

This works once in Internet Explorer but on demand in Chrome/Firefox.

That line of logging is only shown the first time I click on the home link or type the url into IE.  Every subsequent time I see

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

in angular.js

**Edit:**

Too clear up as two people now have asked.  The $stateParams isn't the cause of the problem.

```
if (sessionService.auth.Homepage !== "") {
    $state.transitionTo("database.object", { objectName: sessionService.auth.Homepage, systemName: sessionService.auth.DefaultSystem });
} else {
    $state.transitionTo("login");
}
```

Behaves exactly the same in that it only works once on IE but every time in Firefox and Chrome.

**Edit 2:**

Changing $state.transistionTo for $state.go makes no difference the infinate loop on subsequent usages remains in IE.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the assigning of variables to the `$stateParams`

Comment: If that were the case I would still expect the console.log to fire.

Comment: Maybe this link will be of some use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853844/angular-js-ie-error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting

Comment: Thanks.There's some interesting parallels in that link and a lot of things I tried.  None of them however cover typing the url in manually, when I discovered that was also causing the problem I ended up here.

Comment: Why are you using stateParams for this?

as I see there is no params in the url for 'database.home' route.

`var systemName = sessionService.auth.DefaultSystem;
var objectName = sessionService.auth.Homepage;
$state.transitionTo("database.object", {'objectName' : objectName, 'systemName': 'systemName' });`

Comment: @BotanMan you are right it is unnecessary but it also don't solve the problem to change it.

Comment: @Saurbaum what about using of $state.go (instead of transitionTo)?

Comment: @BotanMan $state.go does the same thing, in that is still fails on the digest loop.

Comment: @Saurbaum, I think it's necessary to see your html structure and so on, from existing info everything is ok

Answer (score -1):

A common trick with aplication runing under IE is that you must not put console.log.

So just comment out this line :

```
console.log("Database home controller running");
```

Comment: This doesn't sound right and if you have a source to state otherwise I would love to read it.  Either way I checked by removing all the console logging and that makes no difference.